# different figures on different canvases using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have written a python script consisting of a canvas with two graphs and a slider, all of which are working as per requirements. I now wish to add a new canvas containing new graphs, the intention is to add a tab or a button so that i can switch from one page to the other, are there any examples someone can provide?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you'll need a more general purpose GUI toolkit to do this. Look into using something like wxPython, PySide, PyQT, Tkinter, etc.

Comment: Or using Chaco + TraitsUI instead, if the interactive capabilities required are simple.

Comment: is there no way of accomplishing this using matplotlib?

Comment: how about just a separate window?

Comment: `plt.figure()` will make a new window.  This PR is probably of interest https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2465

Comment: i am trying to add a bar plot, can you spot what i am doing wrong here please? figure2 = plt.figure(); ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(111); ax2.bar(numberList,stringList,width=10); , i want the list of names on the x axis and the numbers on the y